# Recommended method to pass variables in HTML/PHP?

Tags: php, html, variables, web, parameter-passing

Hi I just have a simple question:
What is the recommended way to pass variables when working on your site.
- get, post, session, cookies, hidden fields, ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- GET when showing data
- POST when modifying data
- session when storing data between requests that doesn't need to stay after the session expires
- database (or other persistent storage) for data that needs to hang around between sessions

Cookies; more or less never.  Anything that you would put there could almost always be better stored in the session.  Perhaps for persistent logins, only.

Hidden fields; again, almost never, use a session and keep the data safe on the server.  Sometimes used as storage points for data collected via javascript, but that's it.

Comment: I'd agree except for the sessions in favour of hidden fields. That way leads to race conditions. Leave sessions for data that needs to exist for the life of the session (or until changed), not for short term stuff.

Comment: @David - I'm not sure I get you; what's the race condition in this case?

Comment: A lot of apps I see either use GET or POST exclusively in forms. Semantically it makes sense to me to use GET vars to identify data to be modified and POST vars to specify the changes, potentially in the same operation - this also helps massively in supporting apps using front-controller architecture.

Comment: A user might want to fill out a set of forms twice, with different data and switch between them (e.g. because someone interrupts them with a request that they need to use the same form to fulfill). So they open a new tab and go from the beginning of the form, then go back to the task they were previously involved in only to find that the data has been overridden.

Comment: @symcbean: using POST to modify data also makes CSRF somewhat more difficult (although not impossible).

Comment: @David - I see what you mean, but as far as I can see the same problem exists with any of the other approaches anyway, it's not unique to sessions.  If I open two pages with forms modifying the same data, then submit one, then the other, the second will overwrite the data of the first in either case (actually, our system uses sessions to catch this and prevent it... but by default it would happen, and couldn't be tracked without the session).

Comment: @David - although, thanks for bringing it up - interesting link you led me to, http://thwartedefforts.org/2006/11/11/race-conditions-with-ajax-and-php-sessions/

Comment: If you use hidden fields then the data is stored *in the page* and not on the server. It can't be overwritten by a copy of the page on another tab. If the final result of the form is to store something in a specific given place, then it would overwrite that - but if the final result is "Show search results", "Add something to a database" or similar, then it won't overwrite (in the first case because nothing is being stored, in the second because something is being added not replaced)

Comment: Keeping too many things in session is usually called the conversation scope problem.  You can't have multiple instances of the same page open, unless you use a way to identify which sessions fields belong to which page.  So if it's not prone to hacking, I use hidden fields for stuff that's part of 'this conversation', and if it's too dangerous, I store a key in a hidden field and keep a map in session.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer Sessions. It is the only option you mention above that is server side.

If you want to transfer information from your client to your server you could use either POST or GET. Remember that a hidden field in the end will become a post of get variable.

Get, Post, Cookies and hidden fields can all be manipulated relatively simple. Which option you choose, make sure you always check your variables to be valid. User input values can never be trusted!

Comment: However, it is necessary to pass data from client to server, so sessions alone are insufficient.

Comment: And sessions can risk race conditions. There is no one size fits all answer, it depends very much on the problem being solved.

Answer (score 1):

All of those things have different, sometimes overlapping uses. Choosing one and using only that in the development of a complete application would lead to ridiculously bad mis-usage. You need a more specific question.

Answer (score 1):

I usually stick to some simple rules:

GET - for getting information.

For example:

- `site.com/articles/category/2` or `site.com/articles.php?category=2` shows me all articles for second category
- `site.com/search/mike` or `site.com/search.php?q=mike` searches for `mike` on site

POST - for updating or inserting data

Hidden fields used in POST/GET forms for various reasons, often for IDs or something like this

Session - for data for one session. Storing some user preferences, user data.

Cookies - for "remember me" functionality and some JS stuff (because JS can't reach Session data)

P.S. There are also PUT and DELETE methods, but some shared hosters don't allow them...

Answer (score 0):

Depends on the site and when you need to pass the data.

If its on page load a cookie, if you have sessions a session, if your submitting a form (which is HTTP POST or GET), if submitting and you dont want the user to see use a hidden field with a form (which is HTTP POST or GET), via the URL (GET) and lastly if its a AJAX eg web app you have several options and methods open to use (HTTP GET, PUT, POST and DELETE - see RESTful APIS for a good example).

Note with all HTTP GET, PUT, POST and DELETE methods you can still use cookies and sessions as well

Answer (score -1):

Session is the most appropriate way to pass spacific values. But if you want to send number of variables in a single time then post is the best method.